# What is the demographics of Coco's underworld?

Tags: plot-explanation, coco

In [*Coco*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coco_(2017_film)), if the memory of someone is needed for that person to survive in the underworld, **there should be people from at least the 13th century** (noble families that have descendants today and that would have been pictured then) - if we assume that the memory of someone must be told down through the family and that someone must be on display (lowering this requirement brings in more people).

Besides the fact that these people must feel lonely (their immediate family is limited, at best, to a few people important enough to have been pictured and remembered), I do not remember seeing such disparate populations.

Is this addressed in the movie?

Comment: Could someone explain to me why this is not in the scope of the site (the reason given for the close flags)? (I am asking seriously, I really have no idea)